# Create a Deck of Cards with Two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, for-loop

I am working on a Java experiment to make a deck of cards. So far, I managed to get the card class working. This sets up card with getter and setter methods for rank and suit and a toString method. One of the instructions in the deck class says to create a deck, using a Card object for every combination of rank and suit. I'm not confident on how to do this and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction? So far this is the code I have:

```
public class Deck
{
    public static final int number = 52;
```

Comment: What exactly are you having issues with? It looks like your loops are setting up a deck already.

Comment: I was wondering if this is the right way of going about this? Also, the class won't compile and highlights "for(String suit : suits) {" and says illegal start of type. I don't know why it's doing this.

Comment: Your class doesn't have a constructor. The looping code should be in the constructor.

Comment: Is `Card[] deck = NUM_CARDS;` your real code? What is `NUM_CARDS`? Is it array or int? If int then maybe you are looking for something more like `Card[] deck = new Card[number];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring your logic in a scope, you are declaring it in the class definitions. You need to put your logic in a `Method` or The `class` `Main` `Method`. I think for the moment you are biting off more you can chew, follow simple tutorials and get an understanding of basic Java concepts, like `method` declaration, `field` declaration, main methods etc. Before you are start on working on fancy logic. Happy coding.

```
public class Deck
{
    public static final int number = 52;

    String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    public Card[] deck = new Card[number];

    public void CreateDeck()
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(String suit : suits) {
            for(String rank : ranks) {
               deck[i++] = new Card(suit, rank);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class doesn't have a constructor (or some method you can invoke). The looping code should be in the constructor.

```
public class Deck
{
    public static final int number = 52;

    String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    //Card[] deck = NUM_CARDS;
    //int i = 0; 

    public Deck()
    {
        for(String suit : suits) {
             for(String rank : ranks) {
                deck[i++] = new Card(suit, rank);
             }
        }
    }
```

You need to define your Array correctly.

```
Card[] deck = new Card[number];
```